# Find images in a Linux directory based on their resolution

Tags: command-line, bash, search, find, image-processing

I would like to scan all images in a directory (recursively within sub-folders), and find those with resolution higher than a specific threshold (e.g. say those with resolutions at least `800x600` or if easier, say with width higher than `1000` pixels). Then I would like to log their address in a text file, accompanying their resolution (or `[width], [height]` for a better formatting).

So `log.txt` would look like this:

```
/home/users/myuser/test/image1.jpg, 1800, 1600
/home/users/myuser/test/image20.jpg, 2800, 2600
/home/users/myuser/test/image30.jpg, 1500, 1200
```

How can I do that that using a bash script? I have to scan millions of images.

Comment: also asked on superuser: https://superuser.com/q/1333517/4714

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Via bash's [recursive glob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49917/85039)  and ImageMagick's `identify` command:

```
shopt -s globstar
identify -format "%f, %w, %h\n" **/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}
```

Saving such output to file , is just a matter of adding `> mylog.txt` to previous command, that is

```
identify -format "%f, %w, %h\n" **/*.{png,jpg,jpeg} > mylog.txt
```

From there, you could use `awk` or `perl` to compare `mylog.txt` columns

```
awk -F ',' '$2 > 800 && $3 > 600' mylog.txt
```

`awk` here uses `,` as separator for columns, and the usual structure for `awk` is `/PATTERN/{COMMANDS}`, which defaults to just printing if `{COMMANDS}` omitted ; in the particular example above, if the pattern `$2 > 800 && $3 > 600` is true, that is it's the image above desired resolution, you'll get it printed to the screen.

And probably skipping the log step in between, it would be a little better to just pipe everything:

```
shopt -s globstar
identify -format "%f, %w, %h\n" **/*.{png,jpg,jpeg} | awk -F ',' '$2 > 800 && $3 > 600' > filtered_images.txt
```

---

In case you encounter `arguments list too long` error, typically `find` command is better approach for recursively walking the directory tree. The `identify` can be called through `find`'s `-exec` flag, and filtering still can be handled by `awk`:

```
$ find -type f -regex "^.*\.\(png\|jpg\|jpeg\)$" -exec identify -format "%f, %w, %h\n" {} \; | awk -F ',' '$2 > 800 && $3 > 600' 
fanart.jpg, 1920, 1080
fanart.jpg, 1920, 1080
globalsearch-background.jpg, 1920, 1080
fanart.jpg, 1280, 720
```

As usual, don't forget to add `> log2.txt` to save everything to file.

Full path of to the file could be handled in either one of two ways. One, by specifying `%d/%f` in `identify` command's format string, or use `find`'s `-printf` option. That is either

```
find -type f -regex "^.*\.\(png\|jpg\|jpeg\)$" -exec identify -format "%d/%f, %w, %h\n" {} \; | awk -F ',' '$2 > 800 && $3 > 600'
```

Or

```
find -type f -regex "^.*\.\(png\|jpg\|jpeg\)$" -printf "%p, " -exec identify -format "%w, %h\n" {} \; | awk -F ',' '$2 > 800 && $3 > 600'
```

Comment: So basically you propose to first log all files (one log.txt here), then apply the comparison filter and have a second log2.txt. Right?

Comment: @TinaJ Yep, or as I just added to my answer, you can just pipe everything from `identify` to `awk`, and save on creating the `log1.txt` in between.

Comment: Yeah that would be better as it will take a long time. I guess you are missing `> log.txt` at the very end of your pipe command?!

Comment: @TinaJ Not anymore :) Edited to include that as well

Comment: I get `-bash: /usr/bin/identify: Argument list too long`

Comment: I guess there are too many results for `identify` to scan!

Comment: @TinaJ  How so ? Are you getting `argument list too long` error ?

Comment: yeah I wonder. I run it on a folder with subfolders, containing around 75K images.

Comment: @TinaJ Alright. I'll add a slightly different approach then in a minute, alright ?

Comment: @TinaJ See the edit :)

Comment: ok I trust it would work! Will test it later. Tnx!

Comment: @TinaJ Very welcome :)

Comment: Sergiy, one small tweak is that right now it only shows the file name, not with the file's path. Can you make this small change? Since in my original question, address is being asked!

Comment: @TinaJ Edited the answer as requested. It can be done via two methods.

Comment: Cool! Looks great.