# Find images higher than a specific resolution in a Linux directory

Tags: command-line, bash, display-resolution, search, find

This is a follow-up question from my previous question asked [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048914). I need to find and log the path to all `jpeg` images in sub directories with a resolution higher than a specific number (e.g. higher that 800 in width).

Well, there are millions of images, and I wonder why the `find` process below is so slow. So I need to optimize the bash script to make it faster:

```
find -type f -regex "^.*\.\(png\|jpg\|jpeg\)$" -exec identify -format "%d/%f, %w, %h\n" {} \; | awk -F ',' '$2 > 800 && $3 > 600'
```

But there is an interesting feature: I have 4 major directories (1 to 4), each exactly with 256 sub-directories. Each of these sub-directories have around 5000 sub-sub-directories, each having around 10 images. So it looks like `major_dir/subdir/subsubdir/10.jpg`. The interesting feature is that all images in these sub-sub-directories have the same resolution; so I don't really need to process all of these 10 images. If the resolution of one of them satisfies, then I would just need to log a single path (the sub-sub-directory path). With that, hopefully I will get 10x faster speed. And plus, all my images are `.jpg` if that also helps.

How can I do this in bash script? So an ideal output would look like this `(path, width_of_images_there, height)`

```
/path/to/sub_dir1, 1600, 1200
/path/to/sub_dir2, 1600, 1200
/path/to/sub_dir3, 3200, 2400
/path/to/sub_dir4, 1000, 800
```

Comment: Yes, always like that.

Comment: I think same type of command could apply, but instead it'd need to process `$1` field in the `awk` command. As for optimizations, maybe @dessert can suggest something with GNU `parallel`

Comment: Maybe even `sort -u` could be added as extra pipe

Comment: One thing is that when I close putty, the process stops. It's a remote server, I thought even when closing ssh, it will still run it, which is not the case. Hence the need to make it faster!

Comment: @TinaJ  if it's a remote server, you could use `screen` to keep it running in a session, and just attach to that session whenever you need. See https://superuser.com/questions/454907/how-to-execute-a-command-in-screen-and-detach

Comment: Or `tmux`: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tmux-crash-course

Comment: Are there only images in those subdirectories or there's other filetypes ?

Comment: Only images of type .jpg

Comment: Yes I'm using `nohup`. Looks like its easier.

Comment: @TinaJ No, what I mean is are there other things, like txt files. If there's just .jpg files and nothing else, you can get rid of `-regex` or `-name` filtering options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that:

```bsh
find /path/to/dir_with_major_dirs -path "*/*/*/*.jpg" -type f -exec bash -c '
  for i; do
    [[ "$p" = "${i%/*}" ]] || identify -format "%d, %w, %h\n" "$i"
    p="${i%/*}"
  done' _ {} + |
awk -F ',' '$2 > 800 && $3 > 600'
```

This test for every `jpg` file found whether its path matches the previous file’s path and only if not runs `identify`. The output is piped to `awk` as you already figured out, I just removed `/%f` from the `identify` command to get rid of the unnecessary file name.